# Strange behavior with colorbox and iframe within chrome

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Basically what is happening is I have a list of videos, you click a video, it get's the embed url from the database and loads the url into color box... what's happening is when you close the color box it fades out then blinks back on for a split second and closes. It only does it in chrome, tested in safari and FF. also it's only doing it with the embeded video, wether I use html: or iframe and href it still does it...

here's my code...

```
$.post('/keep-it-safe/get-video/'+$vidid, function(data) {  
$.colorbox({iframe: true, href:data, width:"50%", height:"50%"});
});
```

Chrome inspector throws no errors except for these two...

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-shockwave-flash: "http://www.youtube.com/v/jvNgktxURM4". jquery.min.js:3

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://myurl.org/keep-it-safe/videos/ from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/v/jvNgktxURM4. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

//UPDATE==============================

It seems like this issue is directly related to embedding a video into colorbox. If I switch it with a static site, it doesn't blink and I don't get the errors listed above.

Answer (score 1):

> then blinks back on for a split second and closes

I don't have any recommendation for this except to make sure that Chrome and Flash are up to date.

The unsafe javascript warning is unavoidable when iframing a youtube video directly, but it shouldn't cause any harm.  I believe it does not occur if you use YouTube's iframe API:
http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/01/introducing-javascript-player-api-for.html